# How to increase backlit time in Dell Inspiron 5590

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron, backlight

I am using Dell Inspiron 5590 it has backlit keyboard . But the keyboard light turning off after 30 seconds how to increase the time to 60 seconds or more

Comment: If there is no setting in the bios, then you cannot.

Comment: You should be able to turn the light on (as distinct from the startup sequence). Try this (from a Dell Manual):  To turn the backlight on/off or adjust the backlight brightness settings:
To initialize the keyboard backlight switch, press Fn+F10 (the Fn key is not needed if function key Fn lock is enabled).
The first use of the preceding key combination turns on the backlight to its lowest setting.

Comment: here the problem is not about brightness. About  backlight standing time

Comment: The keystrokes are both for enabling light and controlling brightness.  Are you able to use Fn-F10 to turn on the light?

Comment: for mine its F5 key when i press Fn+F5 it toggles two brightness levels then 3rd time it will turn  off backlight. There is no option for increasing backlight time

Comment: You may wish to contact Dell Support about this. I have two laptops here (not Dell), both with Keyboard lights, both lights ON, both on Battery. It seems like a user function to me. You may wish to consider updating BIOS and the Power Driver. Use the Dell Driver Update app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just contacted the Dell care and I found the solution

```
 - first get into bios by pressing f2 key
 - then go to system preferences and scroll down to end
 - there you will find backlight standout time in charge mode and battery usage mode
 - there you can increase or decrease the time
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to install the Dell Feature Enhancement Suite. It's an official app from Dell. This is the direct link to the download page: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-pk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=mhvwp

Once you've installed the app, open Control Panel and go to Hardware and Sound.

Click Dell Keyboard backlight Settings and change the backlight time. I've tested this on Windows 10 2004 running on a Dell Inspiron 7000 series laptop.

[image]

Comment: In the download page it showing it is compatible with Windows 7 and 8 versions only mine is Windows 10 and Inspiron series

Comment: It will work on Windows 10. I'm running it on a Windows 10 64-bit system.

Comment: Tq it works but i contacted the Dell customer support and I found see above answer